# Error: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I m a beginner in EF and working on some one else code. The generic repository class has the following **update method**

```
public void Update(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        objectSet.Attach(entity);
    }
    objectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
}

public void CommitApplicationEntities()
{
    objectContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

and this method is called

```
public void UpdateSearchLog(SearchLog toUpdate)
{
    searchLogRepository.Update(toUpdate);
    searchLogRepository.CommitApplicationEntities();
}
```

After modifying SearchLog, I call searchLogRepository.Update(toUpdate) but getting this error

"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."

By doing a bit of searching I know that the error is due to the fact that I'm first querying for the existing data, then attaching the modified entity but how can we update this update method so that it does not break for any other calls in the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you could try:

1. After querying for existing data, detach that Object before attaching the modified Object
2. If querying for existing data Returns a record, update that record With the values in the detached Object then save the changes.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Could you kindly give me an example to explain this?